# Cannot upload file with filename containing open parenthesis char '(' on Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Running a PUT request for uploading of the file on ms Graph API fails if the file name (requested url parameter) contains open parenthesis char '('.

Error returned is: "Bad Request - Error in query syntax."

Same is true for creating of upload session.

For example creating an upload session for uploading file to the group:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{folderId}/children/TestFile(1).txt/createUploadSession`

Url encoding the character to %28 returns the same result.
Issue is only with open parenthesis char. Closing parenthesis ')' is working on graph API.

Is this a bug or a intended limitation of the Graph API?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create/rename files with special character "(" (Open Parenthesis)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612670/unable-to-create-rename-files-with-special-character-open-parenthesis)